# Верхний отступ в HTML

Tags: html, css

не могу понять откда [тут](http://www.mti-med.com/index_eng.html) верхний отступ. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: скорее всего вот из-за этих ошибок - https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mti-med.com%2Findex_eng.html

Comment: если открыть консоль все что должно быть в head - отображается в body

Comment: Сохраните файл в UTF-8 без BOM

Answer (score 3):

soledar10 правильно ответил
Все, что выделено перенесите из `<body>` в `<head>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2):

У тебя есть небольшие отступы, их я думаю через консоль найдешь, а так же куча символов которые нужно снести к чертям, например между wa и header, вот попробуй удалить все что между и поймешь.